# can't push with gitolite - ENV GL_RC not set

Tags: git, git-svn, githooks, gitolite

I've got a similar problem to this post here: [gitolite push error -> remote: ENV GL_RC not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233058/gitolite-push-error-remote-env-gl-rc-not-set)

I've installed gitolite successfully as a non-root method with no warnings or errors.  Hoever I can't push since I get ENV GL_RC not set errors.  (If I try to manually assign that in my ENV I get a load of trouble.)

I can clone if I use:

```
git clone git@server:repositories/gitolite-admin
```

The solution from the link above is to use the following which I can not do.  I can't clone if I use:

```
git clone git@server:gitolite-admin
```

That renders a error of:

```
Cloning into gitolite-admin...
fatal: 'gitolite-admin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I can't do a package install since I'm on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS which doesn't have it in its repository list.

I've looked through the documentation from http://sitaramc.github.com/ however I can't seem to get it.  Any ideas how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I confirm that:

a/ `git clone git@server:repositories/gitolite-admin` will bypass gitolite, which triggers the `ENV GL_RC not set` error.

b/ `git clone git@server:gitolite-admin` is the right syntax, and usually fails for [ssh reason](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/gl_ssh.html):

> In particular, note the `command=` option, which means "regardless of what the incoming user is asking to do, forcibly run this command instead".
>
> Without this `command=` option, the ssh daemon will simply give you a shell, which is not what we want for our gitolite keys (although we may well have other keys which we use to get a shell).
>
> **This is the backbone of what makes gitolite work; please make sure you understand this**.
>
> If you look in the `authorized_keys` file, you'll see entries like this (I chopped off the ends of course; they're pretty long lines):

```
command="[path]/gl-auth-command sitaram",[more options] ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEA18S2t...
command="[path]/gl-auth-command usertwo",[more options] ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEArXtCT...
```

So check and make sure all your lines in `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys` are correctly prefixed with the `command=` directive.

Comment: Thank you!  I've been stuck on this for a week.  Happy new year!

Comment: @yekta: you are welcome, and best wishes for the new year (in ten minutes for me)