# Gitolite: can not push to repository

Tags: git, ssh, admin, gitolite

I'm in a situation where I have a local source tree that was cloned from a git repository, that I'm trying to push to a new remote location.

I installed gitolite on the server using the package method (deb). I followed the [Wiki instructions](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/rpmdeb.html), ending with a successful `git clone gitolite@localhost:gitolite-admin`. I then added the new repository, and my public keys. I can clone this repository on my machine (the client), but am not able to push into it. The [SSH troubleshooting document](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/sts.html) describes [my scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233058/gitolite-push-error-remote-env-gl-rc-not-set) aptly:

> consider git@server:repositories/reponame.git. The clone operation
>   will work -- you're using the full Unix path, (assuming default
>   $REPO_BASE setting), and so the shell finds the repo where you said it
>   would be. However, when you push, gitolite's update hook kicks in, and
>   fails to run because some of the environment variables it is expecting
>   are not present

So, I can clone with

`git clone gitolite@server.com:repositories/reponame.git`

but not with

`git clone gitolite@server.com:reponame.git` (I get `fatal: 'reponame.git' does not appear to be a git repository`)

If I make changes to the cloned (empty) repository and try to push, I get

> remote: ENV GL_RC not set remote: BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at
>   hooks/update line 20. remote: error: hook declined to update
>   refs/heads/master

So, this seems related to the prefixing - however, as I've mentioned, I can not clone the repo without including the `repositories/` specifier in the path.

Is this what is meant by "bypassing gitolite"? How can I rectify the situation? Ultimately, I want to push the entire pre-existing source tree to the new remote (I've added the new server as a remote in `.git/config`), and maintain history.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend installing gitolite with the client method. For me it took care of this exact issue.

Comment: I did that, but am stuck in the same situation.

Comment: hmmm. Have you contacted Sitaram on the #git channel in IRC? He was very helpful there as were all the others..

Answer (score 0):

> git clone gitolite@server.com:reponame.git (I get fatal:
>   'reponame.git' does not appear to be a git repository)

The path of reponame.git is not right.
You should add the prefix repositories/

```
git clone gitolite@server.com:repositories/reponame.git
```

means the reponame.git is locate at /home/gitolite/repositories/reponame.git.