# Gitosis and www-data

Tags: ubuntu, gitosis

I'm currently building a ubuntu (10.0.4 LTS) server on a VPS to host a WordPress based website.

I've got gitosis installed to host the remote repository and what I would like to do is plugin to the `post receive` hook to update the WordPress theme when I `git push`.

I'm getting a bit confused with users and permissions. As when we I run `git pull` the files in `/var/www` will be owned by the git user. Ideally I would like all files in the `/var/www` to be owned by the same user as I think this would be safer?

I've currently got the `/var/www` folder owned my the www-data user, after some reading I've realised this is not the best thing to do. I need a bit of help working out the best plan of action for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments:

I wouldn't use gitosis for that kind of fine-grained control:

- [gitosis](https://github.com/res0nat0r/gitosis) is obsolete and not moving since 2009 (even though some forks are still a bit active)
- This [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7592421/6309) and that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591958/how-to-change-gitosis-default-search-path) illustrate that most features are easier to do with **[Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite)**.

---

So, with Gitolite:

The `umask` use for the Git repo checked out by the git user within a gitolite environment will be the one described in the doc section "[most often used/changed variables](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/rc.html#gitolite_rc_most_often_used_changed_variables_)"

> The default `UMASK` that gitolite uses makes all the repos and their contents have `rwx------` permissions. People who want to run `gitweb` realise that this will not do.
>
> The correct way to deal with this is to give this variable a value like `0027` (note the syntax: the leading `0` is required), and then make the user running the webserver (apache, `www-data`, whatever) a member of the '`git`' group.
>
> If you've already installed gitolite then existing files will have to be fixed up manually (for a `umask` or `0027`, that would be `chmod -R g+rX`).
> This is because `umask` only affects permissions on newly created files, not existing ones.

From there, you can follow "[install gitolite under "apache"](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/http.html#http_backend_install_gitolite_under_apache__)".

Comment: Sorry are you suggesting that I should use gitolite over gitosis. I would rather stick to gitosis as I've used it before.

Comment: @simon: sorry I didn't see gitosis. Yes. use Gitolite. Gitosis is hopelessly obsolete. See comments of http://stackoverflow.com/a/7592421/6309 or see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591958/how-to-change-gitosis-default-search-path

Comment: I'm having some trouble getting Gitolite working. I created a user called git and then cloned Gitolite from github, checked out the g3 branch. I ran the install which created the 2 repos. I could clone the admin repo from git@server:repositories/gitolite-admin.git/ but after reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233058/gitolite-push-error-remote-env-gl-rc-not-set I think this was because the git user had ssh access. I have now removed the /home/git/.ssh/ folder and can't clone from git@server:repositories/gitolite-admin.git/ or git@server:gitolite-admin.git

Comment: @simon The question you mention (and that I answered) isn't about removing ssh. ssh is very much useful for Gitolite. It is about **not using the full local path of a repo**: `git@server:repositories/gitolite-admin.git` is bad. `git@server:gitolite-admin` is better: no '`repositories`'.

Comment: Ok sorry I must have misunderstood, so shall I add the public key back to /home/git/.ssh/?

Comment: I've added the public key back to authorized_keys and when I run git clone git@server:gitolite-admin on my local machine I get fatal: 'gitolite-admin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly?

Comment: @simon did you install gitolite like I did in my gitolite installation script? (https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitolite/install_or_update_gitolite.sh)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9508/discussion-between-simon-and-vonc)