# Setup either Gitosis or Gitloite in windows

Tags: git

Do any of you have the experience to setup gitosis and gitolite in Windows?

If yes, can you recommend any gui tool for gitosis and gitolite?

Comment: do you mean gitosis to gitolite?

Comment: No. Just want to setup gitosis or gitolite in windows.

Comment: which one are you setting up?

Comment: The answer here might help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888300/gitosis-vs-gitolite

Comment: I don't think so. I read most of the documents online before raise this question. I have read this yesterday.

Comment: I just want to have access control to my git repository. Sadly most of the tutorial focuses on unix / linux

Comment: I afraid it cannot pass our ISO standard. Anyway I have a question here, if I am using gitlab, can the owner of gitlab easily steal our code? From my previous understanding, it is quite safe.

Comment: Just use Git! It includes both

Comment: But, there is no tutorial to setup gitosis and gitolite using windows.

Comment: No, this is not what I mean. Git includes gitosis AND gitolite. Once you have Git downloaded and it's set up, you will have gitosis and gitolite ready.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78053/discussion-between-jimmy-lee-and-yahs-hef).

Comment: Just for information, gitolite replaces gitosis which is dead since 2009. And git (even Git for Windows) most definitively does *not* include gitolite, which is a collection of perl script managing authorization after authentication. And Git does not do authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[gitolite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10888358/6309) replaces [gitosis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9928230/6309) which is dead since 2009.

Git (even the [latest Git for Windows 2.4.1 release](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/)) most definitively does *not* include [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html), which is a collection of perl script managing authorization after authentication.
Git does not do authentication, so it has not reason to include an authorization layer (which is based on authentication).

Gitolite doc reports some [Windows issues](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#windows-issues), but the main roadblock is having an ssh daemon server calling git for windows.

An easier solution would be to manage your Git server (including Gitolite) in a docker container (choose [one from this list](https://registry.hub.docker.com/search?q=gitolite)), through [boot2docker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29507588/6309) (a Linux VM with docker pre-installed)